# This Code is giving the wrong output can't figure out where I made a mistake

Tags: c++, arrays

The code should display the number of times maximum number in the array has occurred so for the following input (3,2,1,3) the output should be '2' as '3' is the maximum number and occurs twice. I wanted to use functions, I know there is an easier way to solve it but i just want to know the problem in my code:-

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int frequency(int n, int a[]) {
    int j=0,max,count=0;
    max = a[j];
    while(j<n){
        if(a[j+1]> max){
            max = a[j+1];

        }
        j++;
    }
    int seen[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        seen[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        if(seen[i] == 0) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = i; j < n;j++)
                if(a[j] == a[i] && a[j] == max)
                    count += 1;
            seen[j] = 1;

        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int i,n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int result = frequency(n, a);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, you can keep the count while finding the max.  If cur num < max, do nothing.  If the current number == max add one to counter.  If  cur num > max, update max and reset count to 1.  Then the rest of the code goes away.

Comment: Please note: `int seen[n];` and `int a[n];` are not standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the C++ Standard does not support Variable Length Arrays. So instead of an array you should use some container as for example `std::vector<int>`.

Moreover the program has undefined behavior because at least in this loop

```
while(j<n){
    if(a[j+1]> max){
        max = a[j+1];

    }
    j++;
}
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array in the expression `a[j+1]`.

And at last the function always returns 0 because the variable `count` in the outermost scope of the function is set to zero and is never changed.

A general approach can be written using iterators.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename InputIterator>
size_t count_maximum_value( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( first != last )
    {
        ++count;
        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type max = *first;

        while ( ++first != last )
        {
            if ( max < *first )
            {
                max = *first;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if ( not ( *first < max ) )
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n )
    {
        std::vector<int> v( n );

        std::cout << "Enter " << n << " integers: ";

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cin >> v[i];

        std::cout << "The maximum value is encountered "
                  << count_maximum_value( v.begin(), v.end() )
                  << " time(s)"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Enter the number of integers: 4
Enter 4 integers: 3 2 1 3
The maximum value is encountered 2 time(s)
```

Comment: Not to pour salt in the OP's wounds, but there are several additional critical problems with their code. The code *after* the lower for-j loop likewise breaches array boundaries. `seen[j] = 1;` is done when `j == n` (caused the loop to break). As `seen[n]` is only `n` magnitude, more *undefined behavior*. And the OPs inner declaration of `count` is just plain wrong. Nice answer, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `a[j+1]` with `max`. I suggest you use `a[j]`. You seem to be skipping the first number in your input.

Comment: The output is still wrong, for input array {3,2,1,3} the output is coming to be 0.

Comment: The OP is skipping the first element because `max` is primed with it (look at the first assignment before the loop). There's a problem, but it isn't on the low side, it's on the *high* side (out of range).

Comment: Made the changes according to your suggestion still no luck

Comment: Also critical: He has two variables called `count` in the same function

Answer (score 0):

Start with `count = 1` instead of `count = 0` and delete the redeclaration of count in the loop.

You're starting with 0, then you add 1 when you find the *second* entry that matches it. That's why you're off by one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int frequency(int n, int a[]) {
    int j=0,max,count=0;
    max = a[j];
    while(j<n){
        if(a[j]> max){  // 1. j+1 crosses lenth of array
            max = a[j];

        }
        j++;
    }
    int seen[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        seen[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        if(seen[i] == 0) {
            //int count = 0;  //2. re declaration and you are not returning this
            //for(int j = i; j < n;j++) //3. No need of extra loop it make count extra because you are starting at j=i 
                //if(a[j] == a[i] && a[j] == max)
                        if(a[i] == max)
                    count += 1;
            seen[j] = 1;

        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int i,n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int result = frequency(n, a);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```